# Continuous injective map from real rational numbers to real irrational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, continuity

Does there exist any continuous one-to-one map from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$?

If there does exist one injective map with the above condition, then $|\mathbb{Q}|\leq |\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}|$. But, then we can't go on with this argument as they are both infinite sets. Am I really going in the right direction?  Please give me some hints.

Comment: how about shifting $\mathbb{Q}$ by an irrational number: $q\mapsto q +\alpha$ for some $\alpha \notin \mathbb{Q}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply take$$\begin{array}{ccc}\Bbb Q&\longrightarrow&\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q\\q&\mapsto&q+\sqrt2.\end{array}$$